# using views, abstracting actual tables, updating multiple tables using views

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

can a single view be used to insert data into three tables simultaneously.
am using view to abstract my database actual tables from the end users to directly insert data into them.
the view would act as a protection layer for my actual tables.
but i have 3 tables and want to insert data in them.

but since a view can't be used to modify multiple tables. so whats the solution for this?

do i need to create 3 separate views and run :

```
Insert into View1 values()
Insert into View2 values()
Insert into View3 values()
```

Comment: Views can be updateable, but there are restrictions.  I think you'd be better off putting the insert logic into a stored procedure.

Comment: @OMG Ponies:  dear ma'am, you mean to say that i shall create a procedure and simply give the insert query inside it. that's it. or is there some kind of complex code for this?

Comment: You mentioned three tables to insert into, so that'd be three INSERTs in the stored procedure.  And it would support additional logic, if you needed.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: also, for a mediator what shall i use? actually my boss uses foxpro, and to prevent direct access to actual tables from end users he used a new table as a mediator. if there is any bad effect then first it happens to the mediator table. so in sql server what shall i use?

Comment: You'll have to explain what your mediator is doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're wanting to update multiple tables from a single view, you'll probably have to create one or more* `INSTEAD OF` [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on the view. You can then use the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables to craft the insert/update/deletes that should be applied to each of the base tables.

*If there's a lot of commonality between what you're doing for insert and update against the view, I'd recommend a single trigger for both. If the operations are quite different, I'd recommend keeping the triggers separate.